# draw text with GLUT / OpenGL in Python

Tags: python, opengl, text, draw

I m drawing text with OpenGL in Python. It all works ok, however the font is really bad. 
If I make it thick the letters start to look very occurred (especially the ones which are round like 'o' or 'g'. For the purpose of my program it must be thick. Is there any font I could use which does not look so bad when thickened, or is there another way to draw it?
I am really stuck and will appreciate any answer,

Answer (score 1):

Try a more sophisticated text rendering solution. Perhaps something like [pyftgl](http://code.google.com/p/pyftgl/) would get you better results, by rendering full-quality TrueType fonts.

Answer (score 0):

http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=43

At the bottom is the python version of this lesson which shows you how to load freetype fonts with the Python Image Library (PIL) http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/